# What is the difference between $dy$ and $Δy$ and why is $dx$ is same as $Δx$ when $x$ is an independent variable and $y$ is dependent one?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, infinitesimals

I have two questions, say we have a function $y=f(x)$

$Q1.$ $x$ is the independent variable here, then how is $dx$=$Δx$?

Here, $dx$ is an infinitesimal while $\Delta x$ is just the finite change in x values, then how can infinitesimal change $=$ finite change. Shouldn't $dx=\lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow 0}{\Delta x}$ ?

$Q2.$ What is the difference between $dy$ and $Δy$?

If we look at $dy$ and $Δy$.

$dy = \lim_{\Delta x\rightarrow 0}{f(x+\Delta x) - f(x))}$

$Δy$ = ${f(x+\Delta x) - f(x)}$

So $dy$ is the limiting case of $\Delta y$, Am I right about this?

I was totally confused by this thing that even after seeing several explanations about this, I still can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Where did you find the statement of  "Q1"?

Comment: Usually, $\mathrm dx$ is infinitesimally small difference, $\Delta x$ is relatively bigger change in two  different values. That's only considered in errors though

Comment: People who tell you things like $dx = \Delta x$ or $dx = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\Delta x$ are lying to you because they don't feel like telling you things in more detail. Because $\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\Delta x = 0$, which means all they're saying is that $dx = 0$, which is clearly not what they intend to say. Also, if $f$ is a continuous function, then $\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\bigg(f(x+\Delta x) - f(x)\bigg) = 0$. So once again, according to your "definitions" (which are wrong) it follows that $dy=dx = 0$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo then if $dx$ $≠$ $\lim_ {\Delta x \rightarrow 0}{\Delta x}$, then what is it? Could you please explain a bit or give some references, where I can read about it.

Comment: @Shamim Several of the explanations I saw online, pointed out that $dx$ = $\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}{\Delta x}$.

Comment: Things written as $d(\text{function})$ usually refer to linear approximations of that function (differential calculus is all about local linear approximations). It is not some "infinitesimal change" or whatever. I [wrote an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3725643/568204) a while back, but it deals with the 2-dimensional, and $n$-dimensional case, so maybe it's a little abstract for you right now (so if you wish you can restrict everything I mention there directly to the case $n=1$). Take a look at it and see if it is understandable

Comment: @YashasvPrajapati yeah, that's what I meant and thus asked you which site posted such statements.

Comment: @Shamim Link 1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ooWs_8hzxQ               Link 2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4qqNe_hfoz8

Comment: I don't see where he actually said $dx=\Delta x$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The notation “$\mathrm{d}x$” has a number of different meanings in different contexts,
and it can be hard to keep track of them. And in the context of using
a derivative to approximate the value of a function, many presentations
intentionally conflate two different meanings because it makes it
easier to write out the math. I'll try to clear things up by explaining
distinguishing the two usages.

## Review of concepts and standard notation:

Suppose we have a differentiable function $f\left(x\right)$ and we
think about the curve/graph given by $y=f\left(x\right)$. Then at
any particular input $a$, we write $f'\left(a\right)$ to mean the
slope of a tangent line to graph of $f$ at $x=a$. Using “$\Delta x$”
as a variable, we have $f'\left(a\right)={\displaystyle \lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{f\left(a+\Delta x\right)-f\left(a\right)}{\Delta x}}$.
It's common to abbreviate something like $f\left(a+\Delta x\right)-f\left(a\right)$
as $\Delta y$ (though we must remember that it depends on both of
the numbers $a$ and $\Delta x$).

With this abbreviation, we have
$f'\left(a\right)={\displaystyle \lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}}$.
Another notation for derivatives can be used to remind us of this:
$f'\left(a\right)=\left.\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\right|_{x=a}$.
Note that this is just notation: “$\mathrm{d}y$” isn't a number
here or anything.

#### Linear Approximation:

Anyway, because $f'\left(a\right)={\displaystyle \lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{f\left(a+\Delta x\right)-f\left(a\right)}{\Delta x}}$,
we have a useful approximation:

“$f'\left(a\right)\approx{\displaystyle \frac{f\left(a+\Delta x\right)-f\left(a\right)}{\Delta x}\text{ when }\Delta x}$
is small”. When we know $a,f\left(a\right),f'\left(a\right)$, and
a small number $\Delta x$, we might rewrite this in other forms,
like: “$\Delta y\approx f'\left(a\right)\Delta x$” or “$\dfrac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\approx\left.\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\right|_{x=a}$”,
etc.

#### Discarding $a$:

If we want to imagine all the slopes of tangent lines at once, or
just want to emphasize that $a$ is an $x$-coordinate of interest,
we might sometimes use the variable “$x$” in place of “$a$”
in all of this, with one notational change. So we'd have $f'\left(x\right)={\displaystyle \lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{f\left(x+\Delta x\right)-f\left(x\right)}{\Delta x}=\lim_{\Delta x\to0}\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}}$,
$\Delta y=f\left(x+\Delta x\right)-f\left(x\right)$, etc. But instead
of writing something like “$\left.\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\right|_{x=x}$”,
it's conventional to just write “$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$”.
Then we can write nice-looking things like “$\dfrac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\approx\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$”
and “$\Delta y\approx\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\Delta x$”.

## A nonstandard notation:

In the above discussion, we had $\Delta y\approx\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\Delta x$.
Here, $\Delta x$ is a change in inputs, $\Delta y$ is a change in
outputs, and $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$ is the limit of a
ratio of changes as the change in inputs gets small. But we don't
have a symbol for the approximate change in outputs: $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\Delta x$.

I don't think I've seen the following notation used anywhere, but
by analogy with capital [Delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_(letter)) in $\Delta y$, I'm going to define
$\delta y$ to be this quantity $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\Delta x$
(which depends on both $x$ and $\Delta x$). Then we have $\Delta y\approx\delta y$,
so that ${\displaystyle \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\approx\frac{\delta y}{\Delta x}=}\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$.
This still looks a little inelegant, so to make it look nicer, let's
just define $\delta x$ to be $\Delta x$. If you want, you could
think of $\delta y$ and $\delta x$ as approximations of $\Delta y$
and $\Delta x$; it just so happens that $\delta x$ approximates
$\Delta x$ with no error. Then we have the really [pretty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_beauty) $\boxed{{\displaystyle \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\approx\frac{\delta y}{\delta x}=\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}}}$.

## The confusing bit:

Now, here's the issue/confusing part. Even though in the discussion
above $\mathrm{d}y$ wasn't a number (just a part of the derivative
notation) and $\delta y$ *was* a number (the approximate change in
$y$ coming from the derivative), ${\displaystyle \frac{\delta y}{\delta x}=\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}}$
looks *really* nice.

It looks *so* nice that, in this sort of approximation context, it's relatively
common to use “$\mathrm{d}y$”
for the number I have called “$\delta y$”. And then to use “$\mathrm{d}x$”
for the number I called “$\delta x$”, which is just $\Delta x$.
Since the ratio of these numbers equals the derivative, this doesn't
mess up any of the algebra you would like to do with the derivative/these
approximations. This is a little weird because, in other contexts, the notation “$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$”
is meant to suggest a limit as $\Delta x$ gets *arbitrarily* small, not just “small enough so the derivative gives us a good approximation”.

For examples, this $\mathrm{d}y$ as $\delta y$ and $\mathrm{d}x$
as $\delta x$ notation is used in videos like the ones mentioned
in [a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3775923/what-is-the-difference-between-dy-and-%CE%94y-and-why-is-dx-is-same-as-%CE%94x-whe#comment7775497_3775923) by the OP [Yashasv Prajapati](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/725076/yashasv-prajapati):
[blackpenredpen](http://www.blackpenredpen.com)'s  “[delta y vs. dy (differential)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2ooWs%5C_8hzxQ)” and [The Math Sorcerer](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCr7lmzIk63PZnBw3bezl-Mg)'s “[How to Compute Delta y and the Differential dy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4qqNe%5C_hfoz8)”. For the record, things written like “$\mathrm{d}y$” are called "differentials" whether they're used to represent numbers or other things.

#### Punchline:

To spell out the source of the confusion in the question:
When blackpenredpen writes “${\displaystyle \lim_{\Delta x\to0}}\dfrac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}=\dfrac{dy}{dx}$”, it's *true* with the right side as the derivative, but *nonsense* (or, at best, *confusing*) with the $dx$ on the right side as representing $\delta x=\Delta x$. But since ${\displaystyle \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{\delta y}{\delta x}}$, it never hurts his calculations to write $\delta x$ as $\mathrm{d}x$, etc.

## An aside about other notation:

Not every treatment of these sorts of approximations uses this confusing
convention. Note that the tangent line at $x=a$ is given by the equation
$y=f\left(a\right)+f'\left(a\right)\left(x-a\right)$. This makes
the tangent line the graph of the function $L\left(x\right)=f\left(a\right)+f'\left(a\right)\left(x-a\right)$.
If we set $\Delta x=x-a$, we have $f\left(x\right)=f\left(a+\Delta x\right)\approx f\left(a\right)+f'\left(a\right)\Delta x=L\left(x\right)$.

For example, the essentially the same material about approximations is written this
way at [Paul's Online Notes about linear approximation](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calci/linearapproximations.aspx).