# Prove that $f(x) = \|x\|^2$ is smooth using the definition of total derivative

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Consider the function $f : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ given by $f(x) = \|x\|^2$,
for $x \in \Bbb R^n$. Here $\|.\|$is the Euclidean norm on $\Bbb R^n$. Answer the following questions from the definition of the (total) derivative, i.e. without using partial derivatives.

(a) Prove that $f$ is differentiable and calculate its derivative.

(b) Prove that $Df$ is differentiable and calculate its derivative. (Hint:
identify $Lin(\Bbb R^n; \Bbb R)$ with $\Bbb R^n$ via the inner product.)

(c) Prove that $f$ is smooth

My attempt:

(a) Using the definition of total derivative

$f(a+v)=\|a+v\|^2=\|a\|^2+\|v\|^2 + 2a^Tv=f(a)+\|v\|^2 + 2a^Tv$

$\lim_{v\to  0}\frac{|f(a+v)-f(a)-Lv|}{\|v\|}=\lim_{v\to  0}\frac{|\|v\|^2 + 2a^Tv-Lv|}{\|v\|}=0 $ if I take $L=2a^T$,which is a linear map $L(x)=2a^Tx, x \in \Bbb R^n$.

So $f$ is differentiable at $a$ , and therefore differentiable (meaning at any point) and the derivative is $Df(a)=2a^T$ i.e. $Df(a)(h)=2a^Th, h \in \Bbb R^n$

(b)
I think they should ask about the derivative of Df(a) and not about the derivative of Df which is another thing (the map that assignes to each point the linear map called derivative at that point. the derivative of that map should be 0 since it is always the same map for every point)

So let $g:=Df(a)=2a^T$

I want to calculate the derivative of $g $ at some point $\tilde a\in\Bbb R^n$ ie $Dg(\tilde a)$, for this I need a $v\in\Bbb R^n $ in the definition

$\lim_{v\to  0}\frac{|g(\tilde  a +v)-g(\tilde a)-Lv|}{\|v\|}$

$=\lim_{v\to  0}\frac{|Df(a)(\tilde a+v)-Df(a)(\tilde a)-Lv|}{\|v\|}$

$=\lim_{v\to  0}\frac{|Df(a)(\tilde a)+Df(a)(v)-Df(a)(\tilde a)-Lv|}{\|v\|}$

$=\lim_{v\to  0}\frac{|Df(a)( v)-Lv|}{\|v\|}$

if I take $ L=Df(a)$,which is a linear map $L(h)=Df(a)h, x \in \Bbb R^n$

I get that

$D^2f(\tilde a)=D(Df(a))(\tilde a)=D(g)(\tilde a)=L=Df(a) \tag {*} $

My questions are

**(1) I think (a) is OK. What about (b) ? I am specially unsure about the correctness of the notation at (*).Was I right to fix the question? Should they have asked about the derivative of Df(a) ?**  I thought so because that is what I plugged in in the definition of total derivative at (b) in order to get the correct answer as stated above.

This was my earlier attempt:

In (a) I plugged in $f $in the definition, and got the right answer

In (b) I was tempted to blindly do the same and plug in $g=Df$,because they are asking to assess the differentiability of $Df$ but that was resulting in a absurd: In the denominator I was getting

$|g(\tilde a+v)-g(\tilde a)-Lv|=|Df(\tilde a+v)-Df(\tilde a)-Lv|$

(and usign that $Df(a)=2a^T$:)

$=|2 (\tilde a+v)^T-2\tilde a^T-Lv|=|2v^T-Lv|$ which is absurd

This is what the definition yields if I apply it verbatim. Therefore I changed the question and though that it should $Df(a)$ instead of $Df$

**Moreover I am not sure I am using the hint here, am I?**

**(2) How do I prove (c) ? I am unsure how to do this since I am not supposed to use partial derivatives. The definitions I am supposed to use are those in Appendix C of Lee's introduction to smooth manifolds, where smooth was  defined with partial derivatives as seen below:**

definition of smooth function:

[image]
[image]

definition of total derivative:

[image]

---

Edit: Rewriting (b) following the suggestions:

$g=Df$

$|g(\tilde a+v)-g(\tilde a)-Lv|=|Df(\tilde a+v)-Df(\tilde a)-Lv|$

(and usign that $Df(a)(u)=2a^Tu=<a,u>$  but here I am unsure how to write Df(a)=? I can only thik of 2a^T, but I was advised to use Df(a)(u)=<a,u> so that I don't have to worry about the transpose but I am not sure how I can write Df(a) using <,> and not writting u, maybe $Df(a)=<a,\cdot>$)

$=|2 <\tilde a+v,\cdot>-2<\tilde a,\cdot>-Lv|=|2<v,\cdot>-Lv|$

then

$\lim_{v\to 0}\frac{|2<v,\cdot>-Lv|}{\|v\|}=0$ if $Lv=2<v,\cdot>$ which is a linear map $v \mapsto 2<v,\cdot> $, But I was expecting to find the constant map Lv=2 instead,... how do I fix this?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150735/discussion-on-question-by-some-math-guy-prove-that-fx-x-2-is-smooth-us); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining smoothness without partial derivatives is quite cumbersome, and often not so practical. But it can be done. Let $V$ and $W$ be finite dimensional normed spaces and $U\subseteq V$ be open.

Assume that $f:U\to W$ is given. Then for any $a\in U$ we can define total derivative $L_a:V\to W$ just like in your question. Then we have a new function

$$f':U\to Lin(V, W)$$
$$f'(a)(u)=L_a(u)$$

Now note that even though $L_a$ is always linear by definition, $f'$ does not have to be.

In particular do not confuse $f'$ as a function with linear operators as values, with $f'(a)$ which is a linear operator.

**Example:** Assume that $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is given by $f(x)=3x$. You can check that for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$ the total derivative at $a$ is given by $L_a(x)=3x$. So how does that coincide with the derivative we learn in school? Simple, we look at $f'$, which in this case is given by $f'(a)=L_a$. Now $Lin(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ by transforming a linear map $L(x)=Cx$ to $C$. Therefore we can rewrite our $f'$ (by composing with the linear isomorphism) as $f'(a)=3$. And voilà, we are back at high school.

Note however that $f'$ takes values in $Lin(V,W)$. And so technically you should not think about $f'(x)$ as a number, but rather as a linear function. This actually does correspond to the classical derivative you learn in high school. Except that you don't think about it as a number, but rather as line tangent to $f$ at $a$. And line is a linear function (technically "moved", but what really matters is the slope).

> **Lemma 1.** If $f:U\to W$ is constant, then $f'(x)$ is the zero linear map for any $x\in U$.

*Proof.* Indeed, assume $f(x)=c$ for any $x\in U$ and some fixed $c\in W$. Then for any $x\in U$ we have

$$\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\lVert f(x+u)-f(x)-0\rVert}{\lVert u\rVert}=$$
$$=\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\lVert c-c-0\rVert}{\lVert u\rVert}=0$$

and thus $L(u)=0$ is the total derivative of $f$ at $x$. $\Box$

> **Lemma 2.** Let $f:U\to W$ be linear, i.e. there is a linear operator $L:V\to W$ such that $L_{|U}=f$. Then $f'$ is constant, in fact $f'(x)=L$ for any $x\in U$.

*Proof.* Indeed:

$$\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\lVert f(x+u)-f(x)-L(u)\rVert}{\lVert u\rVert}=$$
$$=\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{\lVert L(x)+L(u)-L(x)-L(u)\rVert}{\lVert u\rVert}=0$$

which completes the proof. $\Box$

---

So far so good, we can see that our $f'$ behaves similarly to the classical derivative. So what about higher derivatives? There are multiple approaches here. One way is to realize is that **$Lin(V,W)$ is a finite dimensional normed space** with norm

$$\lVert L\rVert =\inf\big\{c\geq 0\ \big|\ \lVert Lv\rVert\leq c\lVert v\rVert\text{ for all }v\in V\big\}$$

This is known as [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm), and is well defined in finite dimensional case. Btw, the choice of norm doesn't really matter, because all norms are equivalent in finite dimensional case, and will produce the same limits.

So now we have a situation such that $f':U\to Lin(V,W)$. But since the space on the right is also normed, then we may ask about its derivative. In particular we may apply our previous construction to it. And then by recursion we have:

$$f'':U\to Lin(V, Lin(V,W))$$
$$f''':U\to Lin(V, Lin(V, Lin(V,W)))$$
$$f^{(4)}:U\to Lin(V, Lin(V, Lin(V, Lin(V,W))))$$
$$...$$
$$f^{(n)}:U\to Lin(V, codomain(f^{(n-1)}))$$

and so on. As you can see if $V$ is of dimension $>1$ then each consecutive derivative will have higher and higher dimension in codomain. This is not really surprising. If $f$ has mutiple variables, then the number of partial derivatives at each consecutive order also grows, and in the same proportion. And it is not a coincidence.

On the other hand if $V$ is of dimension $1$, then the codomain is stable and isomorphic to $W$ at every step. But that is less interesting case, because smoothness of a map $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is fully determined per coordinate.

Then there's a theorem that $f$ is smooth (in the sense in your question) if and only if each $f^{(n)}$ exists (and is continuous, which is a redundant condition).

Btw, this construction is known as [Fréchet derivative](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative), and does work in infinite dimensional case as well, with a slight modification that the "total derivative" at each point (i.e. each $f'(x)$, do not confuse with $f'$) has to be continuous (which in finite dimensional case is a redundant condition). Also note that in finite dimensional case all the constructions of derivatives coincide under some additional mild conditions (e.g. continuous partial derivatives).

---

So what now? In your original example we have $f(x)=\lVert x\rVert^2$. You've correctly calculated $f'(a)(u)=2\langle a,u\rangle$ (which is the same thing). So $f':\mathbb{R}^n\to Lin(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R})$. But you can easily verify that $f'$ is actualy linear (because the inner product is bilinear), and therefore by Lemma 2 $f''$ is constant, in fact $f''(x)(a)(u)=2\langle a,u\rangle$ by our Lemma 2 (note: constant here means "constant in $x$"). And then by Lemma 1 $f^{(3)}$ is constant zero. But then $f^{(n)}$ is constant zero for any $n\geq 3$ by induction. And so all $f^{(n)}$ exist, i.e. $f$ is smooth.

Comment: So what is the definition of smoothness in the sense of my question? Is the condition in the theorem being taken as the definition?

Comment: @some_math_guy what do you mean? You've pasted an image with the definition of smoothness: all partial derivatives have to exist. Your definition and mine coincide, it is a theorem. It is you who wanted to do this without partial derivatives.

Comment: If the dimV=1 and dimW=3 what are the dimension of  the codomains of f',f'',f''',... My guess is for that of f' is 3, becuase those linear maps are representen by a 3x1 matrix, but for the others I don't know it looks like the dimension is always 3. For instance the codomain of f'' seem to be representen by a matrix of dimension dimV x dim (Lin(V,W))=1x1x3=3

Comment: @some_math_guy ops, you're right, my mistake. Yes, the dimension gets higher and higher only if $\dim V>1$. I've updated the answer. It is stable otherwise.

Comment: I thought the theorem you are using could be taken as the definition of smoothness(maybe the one you quoted at the beginning as cumbersome) so that the question (c) would make sense when they ask to prove smothness using the definition of total derivative and not using partial derivatives, like you are doing only that youa re using a theorem and the question implies some definition of smoothness that uses only the definition of total derivative is needed

Comment: @some_math_guy yes, that's precisely why I've posted this long answer. To answer your question without using partial derivatives. It is a valid definition, but partial derivatives are somewhat better in the sense that are easier to calculate and more intuitive.

Comment: Could you please help me write the solution of part b  correctly ?(see my edit at the end of the question where I tried to do it) There is something wrong there.

Comment: @some_math_guy the first derivative is $f'(a)(u)=2\langle a,u\rangle$. We now apply our isomorphism from hint and obtain function $f'(a)=2a$. This is a linear map $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$, and thus its derivative is given by $f''(x)(u)=2u$ by our Lemma 2. Which is a constant map in $x$. Your calculation is also correct. You found constant map $\tilde{a}\mapsto L_\tilde{a}$, because $L_{\tilde{a}}v=2\langle v,\cdot\rangle$ does not depend on $\tilde{a}$. Again, read carefully lemma 2 and note which map is constant.

Comment: I've update the answer. Btw, you should not expect second (or any) derivative to be a constant $2$ function. As I already said multiple times: derivatives in multivariable calculus are not numbers. These are linear operators, nested in higher orders. They can be constant (as my Lemma 2 says), but not in the sense "constant number", but "constant linear operator".

Comment: So the conclusion of part b is: $Lv=2<v,\cdot> \implies L=2  \implies D(Df)(\tilde a)=2 $? where 2 is to interpreted as the matrix (2) that represents  the linear map $L $such that$ L(v)=2v$.  A linear map is not constant, but the map $\tilde a \mapsto L=D(Df)(\tilde a) $ does not depend on $\tilde a$, so we say that the derivative of Df is constant (because its value is always the same map ). We say then that Df is diferentiable at every $\tilde a \in \Bbb R^n $ and the derivative at any point is the $\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^n$map given by the matrix (2) Are my conclusions correct?

Comment: On second thought, I think the$ 2$ is not a $1x1$ matrix but the $nxn$ matrix $2 I_{n}$ ?

Comment: @some_math_guy yes, it is $n\times n$ matrix, precisely $2I_n$.

Answer (score 0):

We can make this easy on ourselves by noting that $f(\vec{v}) = \vec{v} \cdot \vec{v}$, which $\cdot$ being the dot product. Expanding out, we get:

$$ f(\vec{v}) = \sum_{1 \le i \le n} \vec{v}_i\vec{v}_i $$

This is a sum of monomials of the form $xx$ or $xy$. Each monomial is smooth by definition above because arbitrary partials exist and are continuous. And the finite sum of smooth functions is smooth by linearity of the partial derivative.

##### Part A

$f(\vec{v})$ is $\vec{v} \cdot \vec{v}$. Let's compute its partial derivative with respect to some $x$ in $\vec{v}$. Let $\vec{p}$ be the remaining elements of $\vec{v}$ once $x$ is removed.

We get:

$$ f(\vec{v}) = x^2 + \vec{p} \cdot \vec{p} $$

If we differentiate with respect to $x$ we get:

$$ f_x(\vec{v}) = 2x $$

However, our choice of which variable to call $x$ was arbitrary. Hence $f$ has all of its first partial derivatives. Hence $f$ is differentiable.

---

##### Part B

We need to consider two cases $f_{xx}$ (when both variables that we're partially differentiating with respect to are the same) and $f_{xy}$ (when they're different).

Consider $f_{xx}$.

By computing the derivative of the expression we got in Part A we obtain:

$$ f_{xx}(\vec{v}) = 2 $$

Consider $f_{xy}$.

$$ f_{xy}(\vec{v}) = 0 $$

---

##### Part C

All single partial derivatives of $f$ are linear and hence continuous.

All double partial derivatives of $f$ are constant and hence continuous.

Thus, all partial derivatives of order three or greater are constantly zero.

Thus $f$ is smooth.

Comment: The problem asks not to use partial derivatives, otherwise it is trivial

Comment: @some_math_guy, how are you defining smoothness? I guess you could do it with a bunch of directional derivatives in arbitrary directions ending with a total derivative.

Comment: That is partly the problem, I am not sure, the reference is the appendix of Lee's book and in the picture at the end of my post smoothness is defined  with partial derivatives.

Comment: On part b however I don't know well how the arguments I give in the comments are wrong.

Comment: Defining smoothness without appealing to partial derivatives is an interesting question in its own right, and it's narrow enough that you'll get interesting answers from people way more knowledgeable than me. I'd like to ask that question myself, but I think it's only fair to offer it to you first. Would you like to ask *how to define smoothness of a function from $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ without appealing to the partial derivative*?

Comment: Go ahead, I will try to get in touch with the professor and see what he meant. And this question can be  focused on my issues on point b

Answer (score 0):

I will do this exercise for $f:V \to \mathbf{R},$ where $V$ is a Hilbert space.

Consider $f(v) = v \cdot v,$ for $v \in V.$ Note that $f = B \circ (I,I),$ where $B$ is bilinear and continuous, and $I$ is the identity of $V.$

**Lemma 1.** A constant function is differentiable with zero derivative. Since the zero function is constant, a constant function is $C^\infty$-smooth.

*Proof.* Trivial.

**Lemma 2.** Let $L$ (resp. $B$) be a continuous linear (resp. bilinear) function from a normed space $U$ (resp. $U^2$) to another normed space $V.$ Then $L$ (resp. $B$) is differentiable and $DL(u) = L$ for all $u$ (resp. $DB(u_1,u_2) = B \circ (u_1, \pi_2) + B(\pi_1, u_2),$ where $\pi_i:U^2 \to U$ is the canonical projection).

*Proof.* $L(u+h) = L(u) + L(h) + 0,$ and continuity of $L$ proves $DL(u) = L.$ The bilinear case uses the expansion
$$
B(u_1+h_1,u_2+h_2) = B(u_1,u_2)+B(u_1,h_2)+B(h_1,u_2)+B(h_1,h_2),
$$
and to finish the proof, suffices to show $B(h_1,h_2) = o(\|(h_1,h_2)\|).$ However, continuity of $B$ *signifies* the first inequality that follows:
$$
\|B(h_1,h_2)\| \leq \|B\| \|h_1\|\|h_2\| \leq \|B\| \|(h_1,h_2)\|^2,
$$
the second inequality follows by choosing an appropriate norm of $U^2,$ such as $\|(h_1,h_2)\| = \max(\|h_1\|,\|h_2\|).$ Then, $B(h_1,h_2) = o(\|(h_1,h_2)\|)$ and $B$ is differentiable with the correct derivative. QED

**Corollary.** The derivative of a linear function is a constant function, and the derivative of a bilinear function is a linear function. Therefore linear and bilinear functions are $C^\infty$-smooth.

**Lemma 3.** The composition of $C^k$-functions is $C^k.$

*Proof.* By induction on $k;$ the chain rule gives $D(g \circ f) = (Dg \circ f) \circ Df$ and this shows that if $g$ and $f$ are continuously differentiable, so is $g \circ f.$ Having the result for $C^k$ functions and assuming $g$ and $f$ two $C^{k+1}$ functions, we see that $D(g \circ f)$ is the composition of $Dg \circ f$ and $Df;$ note that $Dg \circ f$ is of class $C^k$ since $Dg$ is of class $C^k$ and $f$ is of class $C^k$ (being of class $C^{k+1})$ and the induction step shows $Dg \circ f$ is of class $C^k;$ by assumption $Df$ is of class $C^k,$ the induction steps applied again shows $(Dg \circ f) \circ Df$ is of class $C^k,$ namely $D(g \circ f)$ is of class $C^k,$ thie signifies $g \circ f$ is of class $C^{k+1}.$ QED

**To complete the exercise.** We have $f = B \circ (I,I).$ Clearly $(I,I)$ is linear and continuous, therefore $C^\infty$-smooth, and therefore $f$ is $C^\infty$-smooth by **Lemma 3.**