# Partial derivatives of a multivariable function.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Let $f(x,y)$ be a two-variable function. Then I saw in my book that,
$$ df =\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\mathrm{dx}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\mathrm{dy}$$
**MY QUESTION:-**

$(1)$ How to prove this?

I made several attempts but i suspect I am missing something important.

Comment: This essentially boils down to definitions of the symbols involved; see [Help understanding expression for the derivative of a function](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3725643/568204). Also, it should be $df$ not $\partial f$.

Comment: Consider a parameterisation of $f$ in terms of $t$ i.e $f(x,y) = f(x(t), y(t))$. What is the total derivative $df/dt$?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative#The_total_derivative_as_a_differential_form) might also be helpful besides the already provided link.