# Difficulty understanding a step in Weintraub's Differential Forms Textbook:

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, vector-analysis, differential-forms, exterior-derivative

In Weintraub's *Differential Forms*, he gives this property:
Let $f$ be a differentiable function defined on a region **R** of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Let $f_*$ be the derivative of $f$ with respect to some variable.

Let $p_0$ have coordinates $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ and $v$ have coordinates $(a, b, c)$. First let's evaluate $df(v)$

By definition I.2.1, $df = f_x dx + f_y dy + f_z dz$, so

$$ df(v) = (f_x dx + f_y dy + f_z dz) (a\mathbf{i} + b \mathbf{j} 
 + c\mathbf{k})$$
$$ = f_x (x_0, y_0, z_0) a + f_y(x_0, y_0, z_0)b + f_z (x_0, y_0, z_0)c$$

For one, I couldn't even find a "definition I.2.1" in his textbook. Secondly, he only defines this interaction (without loss of generality):
$$ dx(i) = 1, dx(j\ne i) = 0$$
However, I feel he doesn't rigorously make the leap (without loss of generality) that $(f_xdx)(a \mathbf{i}) = f_x(x_0, y_0, z_0)a$. His book also has certain typos and leaps of logic, so it is hard to tell what is intentional and what is sometimes a mistake in syntax. To wit, how do we know that the function $f$ is a map on preimage $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$? I can vaguely try to connect it to his definition of $p_0$, but I would like to know more explicitly how and why he is defining $f$ on this specific point. For anyone who has the textbook or pdf, this is all on page 64. Thank you in advance for you help and clarification.

Comment: I don’t have the textbook, but I’ve written an answer about a very similar matter [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3725643/568204), where I explain the definition and the notation.

Comment: A perhaps irrelevant comment: You might find some of [my YouTube lectures](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd) on differential forms (and plenty of other things) helpful. (Note that if you start with 3510 lecture 24, there was a technical glitch. The complete version is at the very bottom of the list.)

Comment: @Ted Shifrin: Not irrelevant at all I think, I started on lecture 24 and you seem excellent and helpful on this topic. I may just end up watching all of your lectures from 24 onwards. Cheers!